# mocking memory loss configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments

As I understood from the doc, saving a fragment instance should be used when [the system kills the app's process when the app is in the background](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states.html#manging_simpler_cases_onsaveinstancestate). Would it be possible to mock this situation to test out saving states under this specific scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

1. Press home on your device
2. In Android Studio there is button in debug window called `Close` with red cross, press it
3. Go back to your application through latest apps on device

Thats it